# overwrite previous file while uploading image in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, overwrite

I'm uploading images in codeigniter, it's working great. But when I try to update the images, codeigniter automatically adds 1 at the end of each image. Which will add unused images in my images directory. How can I overwrite the existing image instead of giving it a new name and saving it?

Comment: some code would be nice

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should supply the `overwrite` config parameter

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

See the [Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) for upload preferences

> **Preference:** overwrite
>
> **Default Value:** FALSE
>
> **Options:** TRUE/FALSE (boolean)
>
> **Description:** If set to true, if a file with the same name as the one
>   you are uploading exists, it will be overwritten. *If set to false, a
>   number will be appended to the filename if another with the same name
>   exists.*

Comment: how to overwrite if different file type, because user may upload any type, so how can we solve that?